# Copy and insert rows based off of values in a column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, iteration

I am trying to set up a procedure that looks up cells in Column "G" and if a value is greater than 1, copy that entire table row, insert a row (as many times - 1 based on the value)  and paste that value into each newly inserted row.

So if there is a quantity of 3 in cell "G4" then I would like to copy the row of that cell and insert a row below it 2 times and paste the copied values.

Below is what I have so far...

**Note all of this is in a table in Excel. (not sure if that's part the issue with my code)

```
Dim Qty As Range

 For Each Qty In Range("G:G").cells
  If Qty.Value > 1 Then
   Qty.EntireRow.cell
   Selection.Copy
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   Selection.Paste
   Selection.Font.Strikethrough = True

 End If

 Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your approach and code

1. You say the data is in an Excel Table.  Use that to your advantage
2. When inserting rows into a range loop from the bottom up.  This prevents the inserted rows interfering with the loop index
3. Don't use `Selection` (and even if you do your logic doesn't manipulate the ActiveCell)
4. Don't loop over the whole column (thats a million rows).  Limit it to the table size

Here's a demonstration of these ideas

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim rColumn As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rws As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet ' <-- adjuct to suit
    Set lo = sh.ListObjects("YourColumnName")

    Set rColumn = lo.ListColumns("YourColumnName").DataBodyRange
    vTable = rColumn.Value

    For i = rColumn.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rColumn.Cells(i, 1) > 1 Then
            rws = rColumn.Cells(i, 1) - 1
            With rColumn.Rows(i)
                .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .EntireRow.Copy .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1).EntireRow
                .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1).EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Chris

Comment: Chris If I wanted to change the qty of those newly added cells to zero how would I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `qty` - is that a column heading?

Comment: Yes QTY would be the column heading. Its the values in the rColumn, when it inserts the new rows and copy and pastes the data I would like have the qty of the new rows turn to 0.

Comment: QTY is the quantity, based off of that value the macro knows how many times to copy that specific row.

Comment: Add `lo.ListColumns("QTY").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1) = 0`

Comment: Chris when i insert that code it turns the QTY in the original row to 0. I would like to turn the QTY of the newly added rows to 0 not the original.