# Macro to insert blank cells below if value >1 and copy/paste values from cell above

Tags: excel, vba

This site already has something similar:  [Copy and insert rows based off of values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504741/copy-and-insert-rows-based-off-of-values-in-a-column)

but the code doesn't take me quite where I need to go, and I haven't been able to tweak it to make it work for me.

My user has a worksheet with 4 columns, A-D.  Column A contains specific contract numbers, column B is blank, column C has part numbers, and column D has the entire range of contract numbers.  My user wants to count the number of times the entire range contract numbers has duplicates so I entered the formula `=countif($D$2:$D$100000,A2)` in cell E2 and copied down, giving me the number of times the specific contract in column A appears in column D.  The numbers range from 1 to 11 in this workbook but the number may be higher in other workbooks this method will be used in.

The next thing I need to do is to enter blank cells below all values in column E that are greater than 1, very much like the example in the previously asked question.  I then also need to copy in the same row and insert copied cells exactly to match in the same row in column A.  Example:  Cell E21 has the number 5 so I need to shift cells in column E only so that there are 4 blanks cells directly below it.  In column A, I need to copy cell A21 and insert copied cells in four rows directly below.

Just trying to get the blank cells to insert has been a trial, using the code as given in the previous question.

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim rColumn As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rws As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set lo = sh.ListObjects("Count")

    Set rColumn = lo.ListColumns("Count").DataBodyRange
    vTable = rColumn.Value

    For i = rColumn.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rColumn.Cells(i, 1) > 1 Then
            rws = rColumn.Cells(i, 1) - 1
            With rColumn.Rows(i)
                .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1).Cells.Insert
                .EntireRow.Copy .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1).Cells
                .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1).EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
            End With
        End If
    Next
```

I would be very grateful for any help as I have been fighting with this monster for a week.

Comment: Just checking my understanding, so for any cells in column E which are greater than 1 (i.e multiple contracts relating to the unique contract id?) you want to enter a new rows = to the number of contracts minus 1 (e.g. if the number was 4 you would enter 3 new rows). You then want to copy the information from the first 3 columns into these new blank cells?

Comment: Col A has a short list of specific contract numbers that have to be compared to the entire list in col D.  I entered a formula in col E to count the number of times a contract number appears in col D.  I need to insert blank rows below any count greater than 1, equal to the count minus 1.  In the same row in col A, I need to copy the value on the same line as the >1 count, and insert copied cells to the cells below the value.  Ex: if E21 contains 3, then insert 2 blank cells below and then copy A21 and insert copied cells A22 and A23.  We do not want entire rows inserted, just cells.

Answer (score 2):

While this is indeed possible to do, it might be a good idea to look into moving the list of all contract numbers from column D to a different sheet. Even though it is quite simple to loop through a range and insert rows based on cell values - it'll also create holes in columns D and E.

Here's code for simply adding the rows and copying the values as you specified.

```
Sub Main()

'---Variables---
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim val As String
Dim i As Long


'---Customize---
Set source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'The sheet with the data
startRow = 2 'The first row containing data


'---Logic---
i = startRow 'i acts as a row counter
Do While i <= source.Range("E" & source.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'looping until we hit the last row with a value in column E
    num = source.Range("E" & i).Value 'Get number of appearances
    val = source.Range("A" & i).Value 'Get the value
    If num > 1 Then 'Number of appearances > 1
        Do While num > 1 'Create rows
            source.Range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert 'Insert row
            source.Range("A" & i + 1) = val 'Set value
            num = num - 1
            i = i + 1 'Next row
        Loop
    End If
    i = i + 1 'Next row
Loop

End Sub
```

Of course you could also remove the holes from column D after inserting the new rows and modify the formula in column E so that it remains copyable and doesn't calculate for the copied rows.

Generally it makes things easier if a single row can be thought of as a single object, as creating or deleting a row only affects that one single object. Here we have one row represent both a specific contract and a contract in the all contracts list - this could end up causing trouble later on (or it could be totally fine!)

Comment: Glad you found it useful!